# How to exchange objects between client and server without using stub in rmi java?

Tags: java

I'm trying to send an object from client side to server side in order to modify its attributes and send it back from server to client - but **without** using a stub.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read the Stack Overflow [question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I don't think you should tag this with RMI if you don't intend to use a stub.

Answer (score 1):

Sure:

- define your own protocol to enable remote calling
- serialize the object on the one side into a stream of bytes, or more 2017ish: into a JSON string
- send the bytes / string to the other side
- deserialize, update; serialize and sent back.

That is a pretty generic answer; but given your extremely broad input; the best you can hope for (imho).

Further reading: on [protocols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450408/how-to-implement-a-network-protocol), on [serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/239280/which-is-the-best-alternative-for-java-serialization).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a stub *class* in the sense of *generating* one with `rmic`. Study the preamble to the Javadoc for `UnicastRemoteObject` for the conditions under which a dynamic stub is generated automatically.